# How do I reduce/remove the grey bar on the right-hand-side in an html report in readthedown, created via rmarkdown?

Tags: html, css, r, r-markdown, knitr

A basic knitting of an .Rmd file with the installed 'readthedown' template leads the 'main section' to be rather narrow, with a grey bar on the right side occupying about 20% of the space. I want to expand the main part and remove the grey bar on the right.

I imagine one needs to adjust the css file referenced, or add something within "" tags, but I'm not great with css.

I tried editing the 'max-width' in the "content" css bit within style tags. It has no apparent effect

```
---
title: "whatever"
header-includes:
   - \usepackage{xcolor}
output:
    rmdformats::readthedown:
      code_folding: hide
      self_contained: true
      use_bookdown: true
      thumbnails: true
      lightbox: true
      gallery: false
      highlight: tango
      toc_float: true
      number_sections: true
---


<style>

p{
    font-size:16px;
    line-height:24px;
    margin:0px 0px 12px 0px;
}

content{
    background:#fcfcfc;
    height:100%;
    margin-left:300px;
    /* margin:auto; */
    max-width:2800px;
    min-height:100%;
    padding:1.2em 1.2em;
}

</style>


# header

content 

- list
- list 2

## subheader

content
```

Comment: try adding margin-right: 0px;

Comment: @sonia Thanks. I tried putting this in the "content" section but it had no effect.

Comment: @daaronr: get a look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69034784/increase-width-of-rmarkdown-theme-readthedown