# Increase width of Rmarkdown theme 'readthedown'

Tags: css, r, r-markdown, themes

I have a question about rmarkdown. I use this theme, 'readthedown' and I would like to increase the width of the page because I have a huge grey right panel which is not used. I tried something in a custom css like below but it does not work :

```
body .main-container {
  max-width: 1920px !important;
  width: 1920px !important;
}

body {
  max-width: 1920px !important;
}
```

I succeeded to reduce the width but not to increase. With goole inspector it seems that the size of the page is set to 900px !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can increase the content width by declaring:

````
```{css}
#content{
    max-width:1920px;
}
```
````

Default is `max-width:900px;`

But you also need to change the width for plots etc. You can find the .css file in your library `.libPaths()` folder under rmdformats > templates > readthedown > readthedown.css. There you can search for "width".